# In JSTL, is there a way to set omit-xml-declaration for an entire project?

Tags: jstl

I'm working on a project that's been having difficulty with `<?xml ... ?>` declarations sneaking into the HTML output.  Ensuring that every new and existing jspx file inclues `<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />` has become a pain.

Is there a way to set this option project-wide?